# concat Jolt transformation works on demo site; does not work in code

Tags: java, json, jolt

I'd like to concatenate a couple of fields using Jolt (`com.bazaarvoice.jolt:jolt-core:0.1.1` and `com.bazaarvoice.jolt:json-utils:0.1.1`). Here's an example input record:

```
{
  "ts": 1572873208.555711,
  "uid": "CQXg712bv3ayjojRwd",
  "orig_lat": 39.997,
  "orig_long": -105.0974,
  "resp_lat": 39.0481,
  "resp_long": -77.4728
}
```

... and this is the Jolt transformation:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "orig_location": "=concat(@(1,orig_lat),',',@(1,orig_long))",
      "resp_location": "=concat(@(1,resp_lat),',',@(1,resp_long))"
    }
  }
]
```

... and this is the output of the transformation from the [Jolt Transform Demo site](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/):

```
{
  "ts" : 1.572873208555711E9,
  "uid" : "CQXg712bv3ayjojRwd",
  "orig_lat" : 39.997,
  "orig_long" : -105.0974,
  "resp_lat" : 39.0481,
  "resp_long" : -77.4728,
  "orig_location" : "39.997,-105.0974",
  "resp_location" : "39.0481,-77.4728"
}
```

I tried to do this programatically:

```
String input = "{\"ts\":1572873208.555711,\"uid\":\"CQXg712bv3ayjojRwd\",\"orig_lat\":39.997,\"orig_long\":-105.0974,\"resp_lat\":39.0481,\"resp_long\":-77.4728}";

String JOLT_SPEC_LIST = "[\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"operation\": \"modify-default-beta\",\n" +
        "    \"spec\": {\n" +
        "      \"orig_location\": \"=concat(@(1,orig_lat),',',@(1,orig_long))\",\n" +
        "      \"resp_location\": \"=concat(@(1,resp_lat),',',@(1,resp_long))\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "]";

Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(JsonUtils.jsonToList(JOLT_SPEC_LIST));
Object transformed = chainr.transform(input);
```

The `transformed` object is supposed to contain the transformed output. For some reason, the output is identical to the input. It does not contain the two derived fields.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mistakenly passed a string to the transform method. It should have been an `Object`.

I converted the string to an object using Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object inputObject = mapper.readValue(input, Object.class);
```

... and then passed that object into the `Chainr.transform()` method.